# Proving properties about the subset of elements with multiplicative inverses in a finite commutative ring with unity.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a finite commutative ring with multiplicative identity $1$. Let $S \subset R$ be the set of elements with multiplicative inverses in $R$. Assume that $S$ consists of $k$ elements, and that $R$ consists of $n$ elements. Does $s^k=1$ for all $s\in S$?

I attempted to solve this problem by imagining $R=\mathbb Z_n$ and $S=\mathbb Z_n\backslash\{a:gcd(a,n)\ne1\}$. Then it follows pretty easily since $|S|=k=\phi(n)$. Therefore by Fermat's Little Theorem we have $s^k\equiv1 \pmod n$  for all $s \in S$.

I am not sure how to generalize this into a proof, however. Does this work since any $R$ is going to be isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_n$?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Hint: Lagrange's theorem for finite groups.

Comment: And no, most finite rings are not $\cong \mathbb Z_n$.

Comment: I imagine that $S$ is a finite group under multiplication, so by Lagrange's theorem the order of every element of $S$ divides $k$. From this it follows quite readily that $s^k=1$ for all $s\in S$. But someone more versed in these matters may wish to check this argument.

Comment: The first step was to prove that $S$ is a finite group under multiplication which I have done successfully already

Comment: Yes, that's precisely the argument.